# Doubt about the intermediate fields of an extension that is contained in a Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ a Galois extension. We know that all the intermediate extensions $\mathbb{Q} \subset L \subset K$ are given by $K^{H}/\mathbb{Q}$ when $H \subset Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is a subgroup. My doubt is if we have a extension that is not a Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$, but it is a intermediate extension of a Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$, can we say that all the intermediate extensions of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ are guiven by the intermediate extensions $K^H/\mathbb{Q}$ that are contained in $L$?

Comment: yes, because every intermediate extension $S/\mathbb{Q}$ of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is some of $K/\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $S = K^H$.

Comment: Ok, thanks you!